# How to fill part of image with color?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

I have Bitmap image:

[image]

I draw rectangle on that image:

```
    Bitmap myImage = new Bitmap("path");
    using (Graphics gr = Graphics.FromImage(myImage)) 
    {
       Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Black, 2);
       gr.DrawRectangle(pen, 100,100, 100, 200);
    }
```

[image]

I want to fill the entire image with black color, except the rectangle.
Like this:
[image]

Any idea how to implement it?

Comment: i agree with Fabian. but I like pictures, so +1

Answer (score 11):

A simple ExcludeClip will do:

```
using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(myImage)) {
  g.ExcludeClip(new Rectangle(100, 100, 100, 200));
  g.Clear(Color.Black);
}
```